# Why the pointfree style does not cause a problem?

Tags: haskell

I read about The Monomorphism Restriction from the page https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/pitfalls.html and could not understand the last point:

> A common violation of the restriction happens with functions defined
>   in a higher-order manner, as in this definition of sum from the
>   Standard Prelude:
>
> `sum                     =  foldl (+) 0`
>
> As is, this would cause a static type error. We can fix the problem by
>   adding the type signature:
>
> `sum                     :: (Num a) => [a] -> a`
>
> Also note that this problem would not have arisen if we had written:
>
> `sum xs                  =  foldl (+) 0 xs`
>
> because the restriction only applies to pattern bindings.

Why the last point does not cause any error?

Comment: By the way, the last equation does not use pointfree style, that would mean avoiding to mention `xs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because the restriction only applies to pattern bindings.

Essentially, the MR does not apply when we are defining a function using a function binding of the form

```
f arg1 ... argN = ...
```

with `N > 0`.

The intuition is as follows. The purpose of the MR is to avoid turning Haskell non-functions into lower-level functions accidentally. For instance,

```
x = 3 + 4
```

is not a function. However, its type is `Num a => a`, which is usually implemented as a function from a `Num` dictionary to the result of `3+4` where `+` is a function defined by the dictionary. This can lead to a bad performance, since every time we use `x` the sum will need to be recomputed from scratch. This is unavoidable if we want to compute `print (x :: Int) >> print (x :: Double)`, for instance. But actually using `x` at different types is rather uncommon.

So, the MR makes `x` monomorphic, preventing us to use it at more than a single type. In that way, recomputation can be avoided.

However, if `x` is *already* a function there is no harm in keeping that polymorphic, since we are "recomputing" function calls anyway. So, the MR does not apply to function bindings.

Comment: Is `sum                     =  foldl (+) 0` a pattern binding?

Comment: What is DM mean?

Comment: @zero_coding Yes, unfortunately `sum = ...` is a pattern binding, and the MR applies to it, even if it has a function type. (I wish having a function type would be enough, but it is not). We need at least one function argument on the left of `=`. (DM is a typo for MR -- fixed! Sometimes people jokingly uses DMR for "dreaded monomorphism restriction", so I got it wrong :) )